# Replacement for Rhino mock

Tags: rhino-mocks

Is there a comparable and reliable alternative for Rhino Mock library.
I am using Rhino now for MVC ASP.NET project, but am considering (just as plan B) to see if there are any other equivalent alternatives.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-mocking-framework-to-use

Comment: Tell us what you like and don't like about Rhino Mocks, so we can point you in a better direction.

Answer (score 5):

[Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) is a very good alternative

Answer (score 5):

RhinoMocks is a very good and powerful Dynamic Mock library. Even though I have been using it for years, I recently switched to [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4).

To my knowledge, RhinoMocks can do everything Moq can do, and perhaps more. The reason I switched is because RhinoMocks has so many *different* ways you can do the same thing.

To avoid confusion (particularly for colleagues new to mocking in general), I decided to switch to Moq because it has a cleaner API.

Comment: +1 Definitely, I got very confused about how to use rhinomocks when I was first starting out

Answer (score 0):

I advice [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Answer (score 0):

There is also NMock which is very old and I believe uses a lot of magic strings.  TypeMock Isolator can do way more (including mock DateTime.Now) but costs money and tends to be used more in hard-core legacy application mocking so it can encourage poor discipline.